# MySQL (After changing to Percona) numeric ordering changed

Tags: php, mysql, percona

Sorry for the rubbish title.

I've just installed Percona DB replacing MySQL DB on my VPS Ubuntu 12.10 lamp stack (PHP 5.5.8, Apache2).

The problem is, category ordering has become slightly messed up. In that 11 is considered a lower number than 1.

For instance, I have categories stored in the database as such;

```
id_cat  cat_order
1   9
3   11
4   1
7   5
6   2
8   10
9   0
10  7
11  3
12  4
13  6
14  8
```

Here's the table:

```
Field           Type        Null    Key Default Extra
id_cat          tinyint(4)      unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
cat_order       tinyint(4)  NO      0   
name            varchar(255)    YES     NULL    
can_collapse    tinyint(1)  NO      1
```

But the website which displays them in ascending order, now places id_cat 3 (cat_order 11) before cat_id 4 (cat_order 1). All other orders are correct.

Any advice would be much appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. There is no 'ordering' in sql tables EXCEPT that defined by the query !?!?!?

Comment: what query are you running? keep in mind that for you to have explicit ordering, you need to explicitly order your query.

Comment: Hi, the query hadn't changed. This problem appeared after changing from MySQL to Percona. So I can only assume it's the default order Percona returns results (when no order by is specified) that differs from that of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to explicitly specify in your query `ORDER BY cat_id`